# Reduce indirections in OCL code

Tags: c++, opencl

I have the following (pseudo)code snip in my kernel:

```
kernel void krnl(global X* restrict x){ 
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        x[a].y[b].z[i] * x[a].y[i].n;
    }
}
```

I'm using a Xilinx FPGA device, so some stuff might be a bit different. The code works on GPU/CPU, but not on the FPGA. Just some details if it helps anyone.

x, y, z and n are the following:

```
typedef struct Y
{
    float n;
    float z[MAXSIZE]
} Y;

typedef struct X
{
    int i;
    Y y[MAXSIZE];
} X;
```

'a' and 'b' just vectors of int.

I need to reduce the number of indirections, ideally only changing the kernels (or adding inline functions - I've tried this but it seems like the data is not being passed along to the kernels).

concretely, I need the code to be something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    V.z[i] * K[i].n;
}
```

Comment: I posted a question related to this in another thread because I felt like the nature of the question was quite different, take a look if you'd like : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37981455/using-async-work-group-copy-with-a-custom-data-type

I believe the solution to this problem will be passing all the data from __global to __local, use the __local data in the loops then pass it back to __global. However, I have not finished testing this code and I won't jump to conclusions yet. If it works, I'll post the solution up here.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if `a` and `b` are static during the loop then do:

```
kernel void krnl(global X* restrict x){ 
    const float* fast_l = x[a].y[b].z;
    const Y*     fast_r = x[a].y;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        fast_l[i] * fast_r[i].n;
    }
}
```

It is quite typical for the compiler not to cache Global Reads and writes, since global data is considered highly volatile (accesed by all work items). Manual caching typically helps solving these issues.

However, a clever compiler should be able to guess that all that indirection is just a simply pointer offset. I wouldn't think that you are going to have any gain in that case. Example:

```
kernel void krnl(global X* restrict x){ 
    const float* off_l = ((float *)x)+sizeof(X)*a+sizeof(Y)*b+sizeof(int);
    const float* off_r = ((float *)x)+sizeof(X)*a;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        *(off_l+i)  *  *(off_r+sizeof(Y)*i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Sadly, the code has the same result as my previous attempt, and does not make the code more efficient.

Comment: Sorry, I want to be a bit more specific with my previous comment.

I believe the reason why the performance does not change is that the kernel still makes the same amount of calls even after the changes. I am currently attempting to move the data to __local before calling, but I'm having some issues due the "num_elements" in async_work_group_copy. I'll update this or the OP if I can't get it working, and if it works I'll come back with the solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You need less indirection to have less memory operations?

This should be better for a gpu:

```
typedef struct X
{
    Y y[MAXSIZE];
    int i;
} X;
```

rather than

```
typedef struct X
{
    int i;
    Y y[MAXSIZE];
} X;
```

because it could need lesser memory read operations per item because first read operation in original struct has lesser efficiency while latter struct may do it at full efficiency operation.

If that works, this:

```
typedef struct Y
{
    float z[MAXSIZE];
    float n;
} Y;
```

should be faster too especially when MAXSIZE is an even number.

Separation of Y from i as two distinct arrays instead of array of object of Y+i, will be faster for gpu. Same for z and n in Y. Pure arrays of native elements are faster especially only when one of the fields is needed and other not needed.

Adding dummy floats/ints at the end of each struct could change performance too.

Best performance needs thread level parallelism and contiguous reads from memory while object oriented approach gives readability, sustanability and upgradability but not portability since some hardware have issues with alignment. Why load whole float z[MAXSIZE] from memory while you only need z[i]? Because it is in an object. If it was pure array, it would need only 1 indexing operation to get z[i]. Loading an objects field needs a leap of MAXSIZE step in memory even if it loads only a single float but pure array version of your choice would make it stepping with size of 1 and achieve maybe optimum speed.

Example array for z:

```
z[0]:  1st thread's z[0]
z[1]:  2nd thread's z[0]
z[2]:  3rd thread's z[0]
....
z[n]:  1st thread's z[1]
z[n+1]:  2nd thread's z[1]
z[n+3]:  3rd thread's z[1]
....
```

so at each step of

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
```

gpu accesses to memory in a non-holed way for all z which would be much faster than object oriented version imho.

Comment: _it could need lesser memory read operations per item because first read operation in original struct has lesser efficiency while latter struct may do it at full efficiency operation._

This is interesting to know.

I'm actually using a Xilinx FPGA, so I don't think some of the stuff you said will apply to my work. I didn't think it was appropriate to specify that since it wasn't quite opencl or C++ code related, but I'll specify that next time. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Then compiler arranges reads and writes on hardware level so it doesnt need software optimization?

Comment: In my case, if the kernel is not optimized enough, it seems that it will not run on the FPGA fabric. I believe that the (perhaps inefficient or improper) usage of objects in the kernel might be one of the factors causing this, hence the question.